# Change SVN User in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to change the svn-user in Eclipse Kepler (Subclipse 1.10.3). I found several descriptions about that on the net (and here) but that all seem to relate to older Versions.

What i have done so far:

- Delete svn.simple directory
- Delete Window-Preferences-General-Security-Secure Storage Contents.

Nothing worked for me. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the SVN Repositories view. Right click on your repository. Choose Repository settings. Change your user and password.

Comment: The names are translated from the french version on my company workstation. Let me know if you don't find them...

Comment: I don't have any user-option on the context menu in the svn-perspective. Are you using Eclipse-Kepler?

Comment: Yes, I do. Are you on the SVN Repositories view? You should see a list of all your SVN repositories

Comment: Yes I am... I just noticed that I am using Subclipse not Subersive, that should be the difference...

Comment: That's unfortunate. The views have the same name. I don't use Subclipse, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [eclipse-kepler]\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime, remove .keyring file, restart the eclipse and try to Sync with repository, Eclipse will prompt for SVN Credentials, enter the username and password (Save if required), now Eclipse will regenerate .keyring in the same location